# Calling activity if the app is closed

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to create a fullscreen notification for alarm clock. I suppose it should be a simple activity, but I have troubles with calling it. If app is running, everything is ok, but if I manually ruine process of this app, the activity is not shown. It also is not shown if the screen is off.

So, two questions. 1) How to call `AlarmActivity` if the app is closed? 2) How to call it if the screen is off?

It's AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent();
            alarmIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.enjoyalarm.enjoyalarm", "com.enjoyalarm.enjoyalarm.AlarmActivity"));
            alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
   }
```

}

AlarmActivity:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
```

If it's impossible, how to deal with my problem: fullscreen notification (with buttons, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your intent from

```
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent();
```

to

```
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
```

and remove

```
alarmIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.enjoyalarm.enjoyalarm", "com.enjoyalarm.enjoyalarm.AlarmActivity"));
```